# getting NaN while showing data

Tags: javascript

I am getting NaN while retrieving the temperature, but I am getting the temperature correctly when i display it on console.

my code is shown below:

```
// Event listener to add function to existing HTML DOM element
generate.addEventListener('click', function performAction() {
  const zip = document.getElementById('zip').value;
  const feelings = document.getElementById('feelings').value;

  getData(baseURL, zip, apiKey)
    .then(function (data) {
      postData('/addData', { temperature: data.main.temp.toString(), date: newDate, feel: feelings })
    })
    .then(() => retrieveData());

})

/* Function to GET Project Data */
const retrieveData = async () => {
  const request = await fetch('/all');
  try {
    // Transform into JSON
    const allData = await request.json()
    console.log(allData)
    // Write updated data to DOM elements
    document.getElementById('temp').innerHTML = Math.round(allData.temp) + 'degrees';
    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = allData.feel;
    document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = allData.date;
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.log("error", error);
    // appropriately handle the error
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share with as a result of `console.log(allData.temp)` before `innerHTML`?

Comment: You missed `return` before `postData` call, not waiting for `postData` to finish

Comment: What _exactly_ does `console.log(allData)` log?

Comment: the returned result in console is {temperature: '277.32', date: '3.8.2022', feel: 'd'}

Comment: @Tala.sh Then you should use `allData.temperature` instead of `allData.temp`.

Comment: i entered the zip code of a country and entered the feels by my self so when i enter the zip code for a country it returns the temperature

Comment: `temp` !== `temperature` - plus the missing `return` mentioned 9 minutes ago

Answer (score 0):

If `allData = {temperature: '277.32', date: '3.8.2022', feel: 'd'}` then you must use `allData.temperature` not `allData.temp`